# How to use Japanese on Cypher command line of Neo4j-shell and console?

Tags: neo4j

I am a beginner of Neo4j. I am just evaluating Neo4j Community. After migration of Japanese data into Neo4J, I can't handle Japanese on the command line. How to use Japanese on Cypher command line of Neo4j-shell and console ?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using?  Does Japanese work in the web console but not the `neo4j-shell` command?  What are you seeing that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of OS are you using? 
Which of Mac, Windows, and Linux? 
Although it may be able to be simply solved by adding Japanese, a method changes with OS's which you are using.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC8Fz.png)
Dear Egawa-san
As Lee-san said, it seems the issue of OS or console settings rather than a problem of Neo4j. In my environment（Mac） I can use Japanese.Please see the attached file.